# nodemailer with virtualmin and postfix - authentication failed

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer, postfix-mta

Im using virtual min. I have a working email account no-reply@mydomain.com
I can login through webmin / virtual min and send emails.

Now I want to send mails from node.js using nodemailer.

Btw this also works from the command line.

```
mail -s "testing email" mygmail@gmail.com < /dev/null
```

Here is my nodemailer config:

```
{
"smtp" : {
  "host": "localhost",
  "secure": false,
  "auth": {
    "user": "no-reply@mydomain.com",
    "pass": "mypass"
  },
  "tls": {
    "rejectUnauthorized": false
  },
  "debug" : true
},
"from" : "Resourceful Network <no-reply@resourcefulnetwork.nl>"
}
```

I found the following config in postfix config file:

```
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtp_tls_security_level = may
```

This is all set by virtual min.

I get this error

```
Error: Invalid login: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure
code: 'EAUTH',
response: '535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure',
responseCode: 535,
command: 'AUTH PLAIN'
```

I'm 100% sure the password is correct.

If I set `"secure" : true` in nodemailer config I get this error

```
errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
code: 'ESOCKET',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 465,
```

So that doesn't seem to be the way to go.

Not sure what login protocol to use.. Do I need to set [authMethod](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/)?
Secure or not secure?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by removing auth from the nodemailer configuration. 
I now realise `smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks` means anyone on localhost is automatically allowed to send. And somehow still provider a (correct) username + password tripped things up?